# Establishing a simple connection to postgres server for load test in bash

Tags: bash, performance, postgresql

I am currently trying to load test our instance hosting a postgres instance from a bash script. The idea is to spawn a bunch of open connections (without running any queries) and then checking the memory. 
To spawn a bunch of connections I do:

```
export PGPASSWORD="$password"
for i in $(seq 1 $maxConnections);
do
    sleep 0.2
    psql -h "$serverAddress" -U postgres >/dev/null & 
done
```

However, it seems that the connections don't stay open, as when I check for active connections, I get 0 from the ip of the instance I'm running it from. However, if I do

```
psql -h "$serverAddress" -U postgres &
```

manually from the shell, it keeps the connection open. How would I open and maintain open connections within a bash script? I've checked the password is correct, and if I exclude the ampersand from within the script, then I do enter the psql console with an open connection as expected. It's just when I background it in the script that it causes problems.

Comment: `PGPASSWORD="$password" psql -h "$serverAddress" -U postgres < ~/a.sql &` where `a.sql` like `do language plpgsql $$ begin while (select x from t) > 0  loop end loop; end; $$;` Set `t.x` to 1 to keep loop or to 0 to stop all loops and break connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your psql sessions in a sub-shell while you loop by using the sub-shell parentheses syntax like below. However, if you do this I recommend you write code to manage your jobs and clean them up when you are done.

`(psql -h "$serverAddress" -U postgres)&`

I tested this and I was able to maintain connections to a postgres instance this way. However, if you are checking for active connection via a select statement like `select * from pg_stat_activity;` you will see these connections as open and idle to the instance not active as they are not executing any task or query.

If you put this code in a script an execute it you will need to make sure that the script does not terminate before you are ready for all the sessions to die.

Comment: I tried it with the sub-shell parenthesis syntax, but I am still not able to maintain the connection. I am checking for if the connection is maintained by doing select * from pg_stat_activity; as you said, but it doesn't even show up as an idle connection.

Comment: @user3517454 what version of postgres are you using ? Maybe try adding `-d postgres` to establish a connection to the postgres database, if you dont have another database to connect to. Also what is your intention behind creating these connections? Are you just trying to reach max connection and then check out how much memory is being used? If you are trying to bench mark check out `pgbench` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgbench.html

Comment: Our postgres server is on 9.5. Psql im using to test is 9.4. I"m trying to figure out what to set our max connections for postgres configuration and wanted a point of reference.